# Object parts detection

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection, image-segmentation, yolo

The situation is that I need to generate bounding box proposals for object parts, however I don't have any hard labels for the same. Selective Search was the prevalent method for region proposals. So, is selective search suitable for my purpose (generate bounding box proposals for OBJECT PARTS) or does it go against the idea of object parts?

Answer (score 0):

[Selective search](http://disi.unitn.it/~uijlings/MyHomepage/index.php#page=projects1) algorithm was designed and calibrated

> [...] to generate all possible object locations.

Therefore, its output most likely will be sub-optimal for detecting object *parts*.

On the other hand, without labeled data for training it is very difficult to train a deep net to perform the task.